# How to pass options to ffmpeg from SoX?

Tags: ffmpeg, aac, sox

I'm trying to combine and encode some files from wav to m4a. I installed both ffmpeg and sox from source to make sure nothing was disabled. When I do the conversion with ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -acodec aac -strict experimental output.m4a
```

it works fine. When I use SoX

```
sox input.wav output.m4a
```

I get the error

```
[NULL @ 0x251b4e0] Codec is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, see -strict -2
sox FAIL ffmpeg: ffmpeg could not open CODEC
sox FAIL formats: can't open output file `output.m4a':
```

I need to way to get SoX to tell ffmpeg that its ok to use the experimental codecs.

Also I already tried using this guide http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide to install the fdk-acc encoder, but it didn't work. The experimental one works fine so I'd rather just use that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sox supports m4a formats. you can do sox --help to see the audio file formats supported.